# YouTubePlayer not load Ad video with cueVideo()

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I'm using `YouTubePlayer` to play YouTube video and use `cueVideo(videoId)` to load video, Which is working fine if video not contain Ad but video contain Ad then `cueVideo(videoId)` will not load video.

Also seen some discussion regards such problem which are suggested use `loadVideo(videoId)` instead of `cueVideo(videoId)` but as per my requirement i shown image until video not buffer and when video buffered hide image and show `YouTubePlayer`, So have to use `cueVideo(videoId)` instead of `loadVideo(videoId)`.

Does any one having such issue ? thanks in advance for any suggestion or help.

Below is my code to load video :

```
 youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoId);
```

Comment: Did you tried to use the CHROMELESS mode? It should not load pre-roll ads, maybe this will help you with your issue with cueVideo()

Comment: Yes but will not shown YouTubePlayer default play button and also hide YouTube application redirection which is required for me.

Answer (score 7):

Preface: **YouTube does not allow any View to be displayed over its video player**.

My guess is that your "loading image", since it is displayed over the video player, is covering the ad that starts rolling for some videos. You can check this by reading the logs and keeping an eye for a warning thrown by the YouTube SDK.

I would suggest to use the [`YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener) callback, that offers the following methods:

```
abstract void onAdStarted()
abstract void onVideoStarted()
abstract void onLoaded(String videoId)
```

By using these methods, you can guarantee that your "loading image" is properly hidden just before the video or the ads starts playing.

Comment: Thanks, i already handle this all callback but it still not loading video which have Ads if video not have any Ads then it's working fine.

Comment: As I said, you're probably covering the player when the ad starts rolling. Could you please post some more code? Especially the part where you show/hide the loading image.

Comment: Okay can you let me know which method we first get call back is onLoaded or onAdStarted ?

Comment: I would say it is onAdStarted, in case of an advertisement. Also, please post the logs for when the video with ads does not play.

Comment: I'm not getting any error and also hide overlay view onAdStarted but it will not work.

Comment: Please, post some code and some logs then, otherwise I'm out of possible solutions :)